# android koltin, how to detect Long overflow

Tags: kotlin, overflow

Having two Long and need to add them up, how to detect and avoid overflow?

```
fun add2Long(l1: Long, l2: long): Long {
    return l1 + l2
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`StrictMath.addExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html#addExact-long-long-). It will throw an `ArithmeticException` in case of overflow

```kotlin
fun add2Long(l1: Long, l2: Long): Long = try {
    StrictMath.addExact(l1, l2)
} catch (e: ArithmeticException) {
    Long.MAX_VALUE // handle overflow
}
```